# Electrical switch issues

Tags: switch

Ok I was getting ready to wire a ceiling fan and wasn't sure which switch it was going to.  I connected the hot coming in to one of the switch legs to use my tester.  Now keep in mind the other switch leg was not connected on both ends.  To my surprise the switch leg not hooked up was reading hot.  Any suggestion on what the issue would be?

Comment: What are you testing it with? This sounds like a phantom voltage being picked up from the live leg...

Comment: We where test with both a non contact tester and a fluke.  We were getting around 80v on the conductors not connected and 120 on the conductor that was connected

Comment: I agree with ThreePhaseEel it is quite common to have a voltage on a cable that is running parallel with a live circuit. Most fluke meters are high impedance and will show the phantom voltage. Almost any load connected to the wiring will drop the voltage to near zero.